# Why such outlined fonts appearing randomly in my phone?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, fonts

See the OK Google thing in the screenshot?

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by a accessibility option. To turn this off, go to: `settings > accessibility > high contrast text`